# Best way to transfer millions of data from one database to other - Postgres Script

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

There are two databases `DatabaseA (schemaCommon) and DatabaseB (schemaCommon)` with same schema. These databases have million of data.

The plan is convert them into one single database `DatabaseCommon` and multiple schemas `(schemaA and schemaB)`.

What is the best way to transfer data, indexes etc from databases (DatabaseA, DatabaseB) to DatabaseCommon(with different schema SchemaA and SchemaB)?

Postgres script that can handle this use-case?

Comment: Why two schemas? when you originally only had one. Off topic: try dba.stackexchange.com. Don't wrtie code for this.

Comment: This is architecture change. Multiple database Single schema to Single database Multiple schema.

Comment: either rename the schema before dumping the original (and maybe rename it back), or rename the schema after importing into the new DB. (you could also use an intermediate machine to do the renaming and redumping)